# Open an image in an existing gallery with fancybox 2

Tags: fancybox, gallery

I've a simple gallery:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li><a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="/path/to/image1.jpg"><img src="/path/to/image1_thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="/path/to/image2.jpg"><img src="/path/to/image3_thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="/path/to/image3.jpg"><img src="/path/to/image3_thumb.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

In my HTML-Head I added:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/jquery.fancybox.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        closeBtn    : false,
        helpers     : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            },
            buttons : {},
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 120,
                    height : 80
                }
            },
});
```

});

The gallery works fine!

Now I want to open the first item (index 0) of the gallery with a link, inclusive buttons, and thumbs:

```
<a href="javascript:$.fancybox.open($('.fancybox-buttons'), {index : 0});">show gallery</a>
```

The link opens the fancybox but the gallery isn´t shown. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you already bound fancybox to a specific selector, you just need to trigger it using the `.eq()` method to select the `index` you want like :

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('.fancybox-buttons').eq(0).click();">show gallery</a>
```